# what argument does hash -t require?

Tags: bash

All paths to directories with Linux commands are stored within a variable called $PATH. Once a command is being called its path is stored additionally in a notebook called hash to speed up the look up next time.

The hash is a shell builtin command and `help hash` gives a very short description. One option -t is described as printing all paths collected within the hash, and so I typed:

```
hash -t
```

being sure I would get a listing of the hash's content.

However I got this:

> bash: hash: -t: option requires an argument

- What argument does it require?
- What am I doing wrong?
- How to show the content of the hash table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `hash` as implemented in `bash`, I presume?

`hash -t` requires an argument, because it's a request for the hashed location of one or several utilities:

```
$ hash -t ls
/bin/ls

$ hash -t ls man
ls      /bin/ls
man     /usr/bin/man
```

As the help text says:

> print the remembered location of each NAME, preceding
>                   each location with the corresponding NAME if multiple
>                   NAMEs are given

To show all hashed utilities, use `hash` without any arguments:

```
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/man
   2    /bin/ls
```

Again, as the help text says:

> If
>       no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

Comment: thank you, i read the text, but I misunderstood it